# getId3 write_tag() not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, getid3

I am working on audio data in my project and I need to write ID3 tags of my mp3 files, but I am getting this error when calling WriteTags() of getId3 pacakge, I am using [this](https://github.com/phansys/GetId3) package to write my id3 tags. any one has any idea about how to fix it.

I am getting this output in my code;

```
filepath : D:/xampp/htdocs/l8/public/storage/songs/newmp3.mp3
Failed to write tags!
Tag format "id3v2" is not allowed on "" files
```

and my mp3 file remains unmodified.

My controller looks like this

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Artist;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
    use App\Models\Track;
    use GetId3\GetId3Core as GetId3;
    use GetId3\Lib\Helper;
    use GetId3\Write\Tags;
    
    class TrackController extends Controller
    {
        function test(Request $request) {
                $getID3 = new GetId3();
                $TaggingFormat = 'UTF-8';
                $getID3->setOption(array('encoding' => $TaggingFormat));
                $tagwriter = new Tags();
                $tagwriter->filename = public_path('storage/songs/newmp3.mp3');
                $tagwriter->filename = str_replace('\\', '/', $tagwriter->filename);
                echo "filepath : " . $tagwriter->filename."<br>";
                $tagwriter->tagformats = array('id3v2');
        
                $tagwriter->overwrite_tags = true;
                $tagwriter->overwrite_tags = false;
                $tagwriter->tag_encoding = $TaggingFormat;
                $tagwriter->remove_other_tags = true;
        
                // populate data array
                $TagData = array(
                    'title' => array('My Song'),
                    'artist' => array('The Artist'),
                    'album' => array('Greatest Hits'),
                    'year' => array('2004'),
                    'genre' => array('Rock'),
                    'comment' => array('excellent!'),
                    'track' => array('04/16'),
                );
                $tagwriter->tag_data = $TagData;
                if ($tagwriter->WriteTags()) {
                    echo 'Successfully wrote tags<br>';
                    if (!empty($tagwriter->warnings)) {
                        echo 'There were some warnings:<br>'.implode('<br><br>', $tagwriter->warnings);
                    }
                } else {
                    echo 'Failed to write tags!<br>'.implode('<br><br>', $tagwriter->errors);
                }
            }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you really getting that output? Because the code you posted includes HTML in its messages.

Comment: ```Tag format "id3v2" is not allowed on "" files``` this is the error generated by ```tagwriter->errors```.

Comment: Was there a solution to this? Getting a similar error ...